# How to use a variable with AnimatedContainer but still revert back to default properties

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a collapsable note that expands to the full height determined by the amount of text inside of it with the click of a button.

The problem I am facing is when adding variable to determine the `height` of the `AnimatedContainer`

I want the `AnimatedContainer` to take a certain height if `isCollapsed` is `true` and a default height (that is, as much height as needed for the children (same as not specifying `height`)). I am trying to use `condition ? do something : do something else` but because it requires the `:`, I cannot just tell it to revert back to default.

This is simplified for the purpose of demonstration:

```
return AnimatedContainer(
   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
   height: isCollapsed ? 100 : (revert to default),
   child: Column(
      TextField(),
      TextField(),
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting it to null?

```
height: isCollapsed ? 100 : null,
```